# HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream] with preset Content-Type 'application/octet-stream'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, zip, spring-rest

I'm writing a REST GET service to download a zip of photos from an event. Using Spring boot 2.7.8

I've tried different recommendations from stackoverflow, but cannot seem to get past this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/event/{eventId}/photos/zip", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<?> downloadEventPhotosZipAPI(@PathVariable
   long eventId,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
   {
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

      final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(
         response.getOutputStream());

      List<Attachment attachmentList = //~~~ {read a list of photo binary blobs from DB for this event ...}

      int i = 1;
      for (Attachment photo : attachmentList)
      {
         String filename = "event_photo"
            + i
            + ".jpg";
         ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(
            filename);
         zos.putNextEntry(entry);
         zos.write(photo.getBytes());
         zos.closeEntry();
         i++;
      }

      zos.close();

      return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
         "attachment;filename=event-"
            + eventId
            + "-photos.zip")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(zos);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Changed the return type to void:
Since you are directly writing to the response output stream, the method can be set to return void. Removed the unnecessary HttpHeaders object creation:
The HttpHeaders object is not needed in this modified code, as the headers are directly set on the response object.

2. Use try-with-resources for ZipOutputStream:
   Enclose the ZipOutputStream creation within a try-with-resources block. This ensures that the output stream is automatically closed after the ZIP file is created, avoiding potential resource leaks.
3. Simplified the attachment list retrieval:
   The code assumes that you have a working mechanism to retrieve the list of Attachment objects from the database. Adjust the code accordingly to populate the attachmentList variable.

```
public void downloadEventPhotosZipAPI(@PathVariable long eventId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=event-" + eventId + "-photos.zip");

    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
        List<Attachment> attachmentList = //~~~ {read a list of photo binary blobs from DB for this event ...}

        int i = 1;
        for (Attachment photo : attachmentList) {
            String filename = "event_photo" + i + ".jpg";
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(photo.getBytes());
            zos.closeEntry();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a file and download panel in the browser now, but after saving the file and trying to open/extract it, the error says:

"Truncated ZIP file header".

If I run  zip -T event-114-photos.zip      on the command line, the error output is:

zip -Tv event-114-photos.zip
 zip warning: unexpected signature on disk 0 at 778976

 zip warning: archive not in correct format: event-114-photos.zip
 zip warning: (try -F to attempt recovery)

zip error: Zip file structure invalid (event-114-photos.zip)

Anything else needed on the Spring side for ZIP correct format?

Comment: Hi @jn4 try modified code try {
            List<Attachment> attachmentList = //~~~ {read a list of photo binary blobs from DB for this event ...}
   //add above try with resource block here             
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            // Important: Do NOT close the response output stream here, as it is managed by the servlet container.
        }

Comment: The servlet container will handle closing the output stream after the response is sent.Closing the output stream here would cause issues with the ZIP download.

Comment: I am not closing the zos as requested.  I added a catch (IOException) after the try block which only logs a warning, and included a finally { } that does nothing.  Still having the error on the client after download.